# Android Tablet for App Testing

Tags: android

Can I test / debug andrid apps on an Android tablet. They are cheaper than buying an android phone. Obviously I won't be doing any of the phone features, just a touch screen game. Are the apps any different for the tablet??

Answer (score 0):

Any Android app should run on a tablet. You may notice scaling and performance may be a bit different but that is the case anyways with the plethora of Android devices out there. In the end they're all running the same operating system with some tweaks here and there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure not to use the features of Phone, you can consider using tablet. They are fairly cheap. But be wary about the touch screen technology used in cheap tablets. It is next to unusable. Another downside is you will not know how your application will work on smaller (ldpi) devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can test any developed android app in any android device as you wish.

## But

In android application there is many thing you must know to make a good application

1. Multiple Screen Size Android Device
2. Android Version
3. Device Capabilities

### # 1. Multiple Screen Size Android Device:

Android runs on a variety of devices that offer different screen sizes and densities.Android groups all actual screen densities into six generalized densities: low, medium, high, extra-high, extra-extra-high, and extra-extra-extra-high.
A set of six generalized densities:

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

If you develop an app normally i mean without any screen config your app Layout by default will be hdip
If you want to run it in tablet you will see your UI not fit with that.

### #2. Android Version:

Android has different version of sdk. You have to know what is your minimum sdk and maximum sdk config in your developed app.

you will see it from 
AndroidMenifest.xml file in your app project like this

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

### # 3. Device Capabilities :

If you use spacial feature in your app suppose you work in your app with fontCamera  but your device does not have font Camera as Like that.

That may be sensor also.

To know about [Supporting Multiple Screen Size in Android red it.](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

### You can use [Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html) to run and test app the best solution.